# JetPack Compose + Room + LiveData + ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

In a `Jetpack Compose` component I'm subscribing to Room LiveData object using `observeAsState`.
The initial composition goes fine, data is received from ViewModel/LiveData/Room.

```kotlin
val settings by viewModel.settings.observeAsState(initial = AppSettings()) // Works fine the first time
```

A second composition is initiated, where `settings` - A non nullable variable is set to null, and the app crashed with an NPE.

DAO:

```kotlin
@Query("select * from settings order by id desc limit 1")
fun getSettings(): LiveData<AppSettings>
```

Repository:

```kotlin
fun getSettings(): LiveData<AppSettings> {
        return dao.getSettings()
}
```

ViewModel:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class SomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: AppRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val settings = repository.getSettings()
}
```

Compose:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ItemsListScreen(viewModel: AppViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val settings by viewModel.settings.observeAsState(initial = AppSettings())
```

**Edit:**
Just to clearify, the DB data does not change. the first time `settings` is fetched within the composable, a valid instance is returned.

Then the component goes into recomposition, when ItemsListScreen is invoked for the second time, then settings is null (the variable in `ItemsListScreen`).

Comment: `LiveData<T>` is a java class that allows nullable objects - if your room db doesn't have `AppSettings` it will produce and set a null object on the `LiveData<AppSettings>` object - it can as Room is also a java library and not aware of kotlin language semantics.  You should use `LiveData<AppSettings?>` in kotlin code and handle null settings objects, or in the repository use some sort of `MediatorLiveData<T>` to filter out null objects.  Simply put this is an interop issue.

Comment: @mark The DB value does not change, when the compose component is first 'composed/renderd', it actually gets a valid value but then immediately goes into re-composition and in next invocation of `ItemsListScreen` the value of `settings` is null. not sure if it's a LiveData or Compose issue

Comment: "The DB value does not change" - no but once the `LiveData<Appsettings>` is subscribed to will have a default value of `null`. So you get the default value required by a `State<T>` object followed by the default `LiveData<T>` value, this being `null` - I have explained why, this is a Room behavioural issue coupled with kotlin/java interop around nullable objects. I suggest you add some logging to confirm what is produced from the room DB.

Comment: @mark, thanks, if you want, add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the `LiveData<Appsettings>` is subscribed to will have a default value of null. So you get the default value required by a `State<T>` object, when you call `LiveData<T>::observeAsState`, followed by the default `LiveData<T>` value, this being `null`

`LiveData<T>` is a Java class that allows nullable objects. If your room database doesn't have `AppSettings` it will set it a null object on the `LiveData<AppSettings>` instance. As Room is also a Java library and not aware of kotlin language semantics.

Simply put this is an interop issue.

You should use `LiveData<AppSettings?>` in kotlin code and handle `null` objects, or use some sort of `MediatorLiveData<T>` that can filter null values for example some extensions functions like :

```
@Composable
fun <T> LiveData<T?>.observeAsNonNullState(initial : T & Any, default : T & Any) : State<T> =
    MediatorLiveData<T>().apply {
        addSource(this) { t -> value = t ?: default }
    }.observeAsState(initial = initial)

@Composable
fun <T> LiveData<T?>.observeAsNonNullState(initial : T & Any) : State<T> =
    MediatorLiveData<T>().apply {
        addSource(this) { t -> t?.run { value = this } }
    }.observeAsState(initial = initial)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to fetch settings when viewModel is initialised, you can try putting it in an `init` block inside your ViewModel.

Comment: Does not solve the issue - the issue is `settings` first gets a valid value (in the compose function). Then goes into recomposition, re-render the component - When the value of `settings` (in the composable) is 'fetched' again it is null. the DB does not change.